# Java - Parse string to double issue

Tags: java, parsing, double

I tried looking around for this before btw

When attempting to covert strings like "0.00000911" using any of the methods ive seen or used before keep giving me the value of 9.11-E

Comment: `Double.parseDouble("0.00000911")` produces `9.11E-6`.

Comment: @shmosel No it doesn't. It produces a `double` of approximately that value. `String.valueOf()`, passing the result of that, does what is described here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> keep giving me the value of 9.11-E

No it doesn't. That's not a value. That's a representation. It is just what happens when you turn it back into a `String` via whatever code you're using to do that.

If you want to display it without scientific notation, see `java.text.DecimalFormat`.

If you just want to use double-precision arithmetic, you're already doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **BigDecimal** instead of **double**.

Try this:

```
import java.math.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a = "0.00000911";
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(a);
        System.out.println("b = " + b);
    }
}
```